# ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

I'm trying to install `chatterbot` using the command `pip install chatterbot`.An error is displayed:

```
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached nltk-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached Pint-0.22-py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached pymongo-3.13.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (394 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [290 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
        Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
      Collecting Cython
        Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
        Using cached cymem-2.0.7-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (28 kB)
      Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
        Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
        Using cached murmurhash-1.0.9-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (18 kB)
      Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
        Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
      Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached srsly-1.0.6-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (194 kB)
      Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached numpy-1.24.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (14.8 MB)
      Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached tqdm-4.65.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
      Collecting colorama (from tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0->thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8)
        Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: preshed, thinc, blis
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for preshed (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [23 lines of output]
        C:\Users\nva17\Desktop\NaumenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          warnings.warn(
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed\tests
        copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\preshed
        running build_ext
        building 'preshed.maps' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for preshed
        Running setup.py clean for preshed
        Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for thinc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [168 lines of output]
        C:\Users\nva17\Desktop\NaumenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          warnings.warn(
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\check.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\describe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\i2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\loss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\rates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\t2t.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\t2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\v2v.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\strategies.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\test_api_funcs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        copying thinc\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_affine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_beam_search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_check_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_difference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_feature_extracter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_hash_embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_linear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_loss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_mem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_ops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pooling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_pytorch_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_rates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\test_rnn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        copying thinc\tests\unit\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\unit
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_affine_learns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_basic_tagger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_batch_norm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_feed_forward.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_mnist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_roundtrip_bytes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\test_shape_check.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        copying thinc\tests\integration\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\integration
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\linear
        copying thinc\tests\linear\test_avgtron.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\linear
        copying thinc\tests\linear\test_linear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\linear
        copying thinc\tests\linear\test_sparse_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\linear
        copying thinc\tests\linear\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\tests\linear
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\mem.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\pooling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\train.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\vec2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\vecs2vec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\vecs2vecs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\_lsuv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\hpbff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\load_nlp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\visualizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\affine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\attention.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\batchnorm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\convolution.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\difference.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\elu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\encoder_decoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\feature_extracter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\feed_forward.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\function_layer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\hash_embed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\layernorm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\maxout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\multiheaded_attention.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\relu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\resnet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\rnn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\selu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\softmax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\static_vectors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        copying thinc\neural\_classes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural\_classes
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\_vendorized
        copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\_vendorized
        copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_data_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\_vendorized
        copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\keras_generic_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\_vendorized
        copying thinc\extra\_vendorized\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\_vendorized
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\wrapt
        copying thinc\extra\wrapt\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\wrapt
        copying thinc\extra\wrapt\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\wrapt
        copying thinc\extra\wrapt\wrappers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\wrapt
        copying thinc\extra\wrapt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra\wrapt
        copying thinc\linalg.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\structs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\typedefs.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\cpu.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\linalg.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\structs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\typedefs.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\compile_time_constants.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\linalg.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\structs.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\typedefs.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc
        copying thinc\linear\avgtron.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\features.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\linear.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\serialize.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\sparse.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\avgtron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\features.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\serialize.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\sparse.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\avgtron.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\features.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\linear.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\serialize.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\linear\sparse.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\linear
        copying thinc\neural\ops.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\optimizers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\_aligned_alloc.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\cpu.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\ops.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\ops.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\optimizers.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\neural\_aligned_alloc.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\neural
        copying thinc\extra\cache.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\eg.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\mb.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\search.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\cache.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\eg.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\mb.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\search.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\cache.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\eg.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\mb.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        copying thinc\extra\search.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\thinc\extra
        running build_ext
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
        Running setup.py clean for thinc
        Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [23 lines of output]
        BLIS_COMPILER? None
        C:\Users\nva17\Desktop\NaumenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          warnings.warn(
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis\tests
        copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis\tests
        copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\blis
        running build_ext
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
        Running setup.py clean for blis
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried to install via GitHub, update pip - didn't work. What to do, maybe someone has experienced it?

Answer (score 1):

The error log says:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

You should follow the link and install Microsoft C++ Build Tools!

Comment: Ok,I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.x and Visual Studio 2020. Now I have another problem
 python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [37 lines of output]
        C:\Users\nva17\Desktop\NaumenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
        !!

 
                Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
                If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.

Comment: I tried pip install `pip install --use-pep517`
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

Comment: `pip install --use-pep517 chatterbot`

Comment: same error C:\Users\nva17\Desktop\NaumenBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated. !! Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer. If you are using pip, you can try pip install --use-pep517.

Answer (score 1):

Make a virtual environment with python 3.7 that did it for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In other words make sure your right environment is activated... 